# Integration of rational function with substitution

Tags: integration

I am having trouble with integrating this function with substitution.

$
\int\frac{x^2-4x}{x-2\sqrt{x}}dx
$

First i do this:

$
u=\sqrt{x}
$

$
du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx
$

$
dx=\frac{du}{\frac{1}{{2\sqrt{x}}}}
$

then this:

$
\int\frac{x^2-4x}{x-2u} \frac{du}{\frac{1}{{2\sqrt{x}}}}
$

But now i don't know if what i have done is correct and know how to proceed. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$(x-2\sqrt{x})(x+2\sqrt{x})=x^2-4x$$

Answer (score 0):

If you note that with your substitution follows $x=u^2$ and $x^2=u^4$ you get

$\int \frac{x^2-4x}{x-2\sqrt{x}}dx=2\int u^2(u+2)du$

for $u=\sqrt{x}$ from which you should be able to continue.